# Encapsulation in header files

Tags: c++, header-files

I have a header file with 2 classes. class A (which is a very big class) and class B that inherits class A. I don't want people to be allowed to create objects of class A or even be able to see its static members. They should only to work with class B. What is the best way of doing that.

(Generally speaking A is a "helper class")

Comment: Make class `A` a private class inside of class `B` or move it completely to `B`'s translation unit in an unnamed namespace.

Comment: If the class A is a "helper" class, then maybe you should not have a "is-a" relationship between A and B, i.e. B should not inherit from A. Instead A could be a member of the B class, using [the pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

Comment: I think you can make class A abstract class.

Comment: What do you mean by "to see" in "or even be able **to see** its static members." Do you mean "prevent programmatic access them, even if the programmers know/can read the header" or do you mean "opaque definition of class A, I'd prefer the consumer of the code not to have class A exposed to their reading"?

Comment: _class A (which is a very big class)_ warning: code smell. [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) is a good thing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To restrict the creation of the class, make the constructor of class A private and declare class B as a friend class. This way only B can instantiate A.

```
class B;
class A
{
private:
    A();
    friend class B;
};
```

The same applies to methods (static or not): make them all private and the friend statement will allow B to access A's members.

**Edit**: works with protected as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want people to be allowed to create objects of class A

What you are looking for is called an "abstract base class". In C++, any class that has at least one abstract member is automatically an abstract class, there is no additional keyword like in other languages.

```
class A
{
   public:
      virtual void Test() = 0; // abstract, has no implementation
};

class B : public A
{
   public:
      virtual void Test() {} // not abstract, has an implementation
};

int main()
{
  A a; // this will produce a compiler error.
  B b; // this is fine

  return 0;
}
```

> or even be able to see its static members

Well, don't make them public. Either make them `protected` or `private` and grant `friend` access to your B class.

Comment: you can still access the static members of the class in an abstract base class so that doesn't help

Comment: also everyone can inherit from the class and change the pure virtual method so that's another problem

Comment: @OferMagen While both is correct, none of it was specified by the OP as a requirement. It's a problem *you think the OP has*. But we cannot know. Matter of fact my "solution" for the static members is the very same as the upvoted accepted answer, so I don't know what's wrong with that.

Comment: @OferMagen I see you *are* the OP. Maybe you want to refine the requirements instead of downvoting me for somthing you never asked for?